"Page not found" while on page 2 from pagination menu
all. I'm getting a "Page not found" message in my firefox tab when I click page 2 in my pagination menu. What's odd is, the content shows up just fine on all paginated pages. I've tried millions of times to change the permalink structure and equal times just saving the permalink structure hoping something would resolve, but it never does. Honestly, I'm not even sure which bits of code to paste for anyone to troubleshoot but I'll start how I imagined the flow:
On index.php, I have three "tabs" called [ALL] [ARIZONA WINE] [ARIZONA BEER]. ALL is simply a wp_query that culminates Arizona Wine and Arizona Beer in to one tab. Then Arizona Wine and Arizona Beer tabs are custom post types that display their respective content.
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
        'post_type'         => array('arizona_wine', 'arizona_beer'),
        'paged'             => $paged
);
$cptposts = new WP_Query($args);

Then I'll call the paginated links as such:
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
        'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'     => $cptposts->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => __('Back'),
        'next_text' => __('Next'),
) );

Like, I feel the above code is pretty straight forward but I must have something wrong and any help would be super appreciated.
Thanks in advance, everyone!

See this answer for the reason you get a 404, and how to fix it.

Thanks for that direction. I have created and am now using home.php, added the function and removed my wp_query from home.php. However, is there a method in pulling in my custom post types rather than just plain posts?

I edited the function to follow the example of wp_query to see if that would work but didn't do anything:
function only_12_posts_on_homepage( \WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set(
          'posts_per_page', 12,
          'orderby', 'rand',
          'post_type', array('arizona_wine', 'arizona_beer')
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_12_posts_on_homepage' );


You're on the right track. You need to use the $query->set() method on each key/value pair; you can't combine them all. So you'll want:
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
etc.

Wow! You both are the bomb.com! It's working as expected. Thanks so much for your help! Just to understand, this method should be employed each time you want pagination on what ever page you specify?
